# Javascript, search/filter sqli table issues

Tags: javascript, php, html

having issues with filtering my table. I want the entire row to be visible if the search comes up with any matches in its respective cells. 
Currently it is only showing exact cells.

```
<input type="text" id="searchText" />
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function contains(text_one, text_two) {
      if (text_one.indexOf(text_two) != -1)
        return true;
    }

    $("#searchText").keyup(function () {
      var searchText = $("#searchText").val().toLowerCase()
      $("tr td").each(function () {
        if (!contains($(this).text().toLowerCase(), searchText))
          $(this).hide();
        else
          $(this).show();

      });;
    });;
  </script>
```

Im using this format for my MySqli table.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1, MYSQLI_ASSOC)):?>


<table border="1">
<!--<table class="fixed" border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1"> -->
  <col width="100px" />
  <col width="100px" />
  <col width="100px" />
  <col width="100px" />
  <col width="100px" /><tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['id'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['name'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['posted'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['category'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['more'];?></td>
</tr>

<?php endwhile;

?>

</table>
```

Comment: If the tr td for each finds a match did you want to exit the loop early?

Comment: @arodjabel want to return all results that contain whatever the user searches for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should loop over rows and cells separately. In the row loop, hide the row by default. Then when you loop over the cells, show the row if any of the cells matches the search text.

```js
$("#searchText").keyup(function() {
  var searchText = $("#searchText").val().toLowerCase()
  $("tr").each(function() {
    var row = $(this);
    row.hide();
    $("td", row).each(function() {
      if (contains($(this).text().toLowerCase(), searchText)) {
        row.show();
        return false; // no need to keep looping over cells in this row
      }
    });
  });
});

function contains(text_one, text_two) {
  if (text_one.indexOf(text_two) != -1)
    return true;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="searchText">
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>Row 1 Field 1 abc</td>
    <td>Row 1 Field 2 def</td>
    <td>Row 1 Field 3 ghi</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 2 Field 1 jkl</td>
    <td>Row 2 Field 2 def</td>
    <td>Row 2 Field 3 pqr</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 3 Field 1 abc</td>
    <td>Row 3 Field 2 vwx</td>
    <td>Row 3 Field 3 yz</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

In `$.each`, returning `false` from the iteration function tells jQuery to stop looping.

Comment: Appreciate the feedback, seems this isnt working though. ;c

Comment: incredible! youre the man!
only issue is the cosmetics of the table lines remaining/being smashed together, is that an easy fix?

Comment: What do you want to happen instead? Leave the old row there, but blanked out? Instead of `.hide()`, you can use `.css('visibility', 'invisible')` for this.

Comment: At the moment, as is, the row collapses into squeezed lines.
When i try the row.css it currently isnt working.
forgive my beginner questions, im able to incorporate css here?

Comment: and unfortunately the <tr><th> Column titles are being filtered out as well.

Comment: You can use `$("tr:gt(0)")` to skip the header row, or `tr:has("td")` to only do rows that contain `<td>` elements.

Comment: Sorry, should be `hidden` and `visible` (surely you could have looked up the CSS and pointed out my error).

Comment: forgive me, im a bit in over my head here, i wouldnt know where to start with css. 
anyways, Now the table just "whites out" the rows.. i want the rows to disappear and the table to collapse and become smaller. go from 10 visible records to 3 visible records, for example.

Comment: That's what my original code does, I thought it wasn't what you wanted.

Comment: The original code collapsed the table but kept the thin lines of the table.
So there would be one record, then id see 7 thin lines then the next record.
Am i making sense?

Comment: I added a border to my snippet. When I filter it, I don't see the thin lines. If you're seeing something different, please make a snippet that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: can you post that original code again, i can play with my borders.

Comment: updated my table code, in my original post, still seeing lines between tables.

Comment: You shouldn't have `<table>` inside the `while` loop. You create the table and header once, then you loop to add the data rows.

Comment: Oh christ. Thanks dude.

Answer (score 0):

```
function contains(text_one, text_two) {
    if (text_one.indexOf(text_two) != -1)
        return true;
    return false;
}

console.log(contains('the cell name', 'name')); //true
console.log(contains('the cell name', 'na')); //true 
console.log(contains('the cell name', 'th')); //true
console.log(contains('the cell name', 't')); //true
console.log(contains('the cell name', 'the cell')); //true
console.log(contains('the cell name', 'help')); //false
console.log(contains('the cell name', '')); //true
console.log(contains('the cell name', 'blue forty two')); //false
```

These results lead me to believe that you should exit your for loop as soon as you find a cell which has a substring match.

Comment: There's no `for` loop, he's using `.each()`.

Comment: You are right, I should have said exit the iteration, I was generalizing.